# Grep to extract one-line comments starting with or enclosed in forward slash/asterisk

Tags: archlinux

I'm trying to make a regex to identify a comment. It has to start with // and end with a new line or a *) pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your inputfile it is hard to understand what you want.
I think the comments don't start at the beginning of the line and you only want to see the comments. Try this:

```
grep -Eon '//.*|^/\*.*\*/' WindchillFactor.java
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ grep -n -E '^//|^/\*.*\*/$' j.java
2:/* Computation done in imperial units. FIXME: Use metric! */
5:// FIXME: change formula to metric units
11:/* FIXME: use floats?? */
14:// hmmm... FIXME: use symbol??
```

Note that I extended the version w/ `/*` to NOT match on the first line 
of a multi-line comment.

Comment: you may want to use your actual filename?